# Using bash's "source" command return error though it successfully read config file

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want my bash script to read parameters from config file.
Here is what inside the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/myscript/conf/config.conf

echo "$username"
```

and below is my config.conf:

```
username="jonas"
```

The output when I run the script:

```
[user@machinename bin]$ . thescript
: No such file or directoryonfig.conf
: command not found
jonas
```

Here I am confused, though it successfully print "jonas", why is there error "No such file or directory" and "command not found"?

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the error message has translated perfectly from your machine to this question? The error message `No such file or directoryonfig.conf` indicates that something in your script (perhaps a part not shown?) is cutting off `/home/myscript/conf/c` from the source command.

Comment: In addition, the leading colons in the error messages do not look right.

Comment: Your source file probably has Windows or Mac line endings. Fix that and the issue should go away.

Comment: Thanks everyone, it is as @Mat pointed out. It is solved now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Mat pointed out, `thescript` probably has Windows newlines (carriage return/CR followed by line feed aka. LF). Compare:

```
$ echo : No such file or directoryonfig.conf
: No such file or directoryonfig.conf
$ printf '/[.................]/conf/config.conf\r: No such file or directory\n'
: No such file or directoryonfig.conf
```

[Use `dos2unix thescript`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/052) to fix it.

Comment: Hi @l0b0 and @Mat, it is exactly as you said, when I do `file config.conf`, it says `config.conf: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators` and when I do `sed -n l config.conf` it shows the CR at every line. Thanks for pointing out the link, it is very useful!